# Is there an undo-tree plugin for VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins

In Vim there's [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) and similar plugins for keeping track of all undos and redos you do.

That's in my opinion invaluable when debugging and experimenting with code.

Is there a similar plugin for VS Code?

---

I'm not looking for a Vim-based solution, because I'm not the one in need for it. I'm just fine with using terminal Vim. The point is *how can a VSCode non-Vim user have full control of the history of changes, just like Vim undotree plugin allows to do in Vim*?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/20889  A failed effort to get it natively.  I got here looking for whether it was available as a plugin instead.

Comment: They added local history (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history) but it is not as smooth as UT. You could also try using vscode-neovim to get undotree directly (https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim) haven't tried this myself yet though.

Comment: Update: I tried vscode-neovim and [support for external buffers is lacking](https://github.com/vscode-neovim/vscode-neovim/issues/505)